# Removing specific occurrence of "warning: unused value declaration"

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to use warning decorators (`[@*ocaml.warning]`) to locally remove a warning about a specific unused function, but I can't find the right syntax (if there is one). I'm using OCaml 4.02.1.

In the code below, I have the `dbg` function which is not exported and never used, but for which I'd like to silence warning 32 (`unused value dbg`).

I want to keep warnings activated elsewhere in the code, to avoid accidental mistakes.

I tried putting all kinds of decorators around the function, but the warning still appears:

A.mli:

```
val f : unit -> unit
```

A.ml:

```
let f () = ()

[@@ocaml.warning "-32"]
let dbg () = () [@ocaml.warning "-32"]
[@@ocaml.warning "-32"]

let bla () = ()
```

`ocamlc -w +a a.mli a.ml` results in:

```
File "a.ml", line 4, characters 4-7:
Warning 32: unused value dbg.
File "a.ml", line 7, characters 4-7:
Warning 32: unused value bla.
```

Note that adding `[@@@ocaml.warning "-32"]` before `let dbg` works (it removes the warning), but then I have to add `[@@@ocaml.warning "+32"]` afterwards to re-enable it, which is not ideal, since it *enables* warnings even when they were not present in the first place.

For instance, if I then compiled with `ocamlc a.mli a.ml`, this would add an unwanted warning.

Is there a way to locally disable warning 32?

Comment: Could you write the version number of your OCaml in the question, since this might be fixed in the future.

Comment: Done, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Your snippet works in ocaml 4.07

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no way to stop individual warning 32 in OCaml 4.02.3.

I had the same trouble at trying to suppress a warning (mine was 39) of one specific toplevel `let`.  The ticket is http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6677 and http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6586.

What you can do so far is to declare such variables with `_` prefix:

```
let _dbg () = ()
```

since variables start with `_` is the out of the scope of warning 32.  The downside is that there is no tool available to warn if such `_` prefixed value is actually used in your code.

Comment: Actually, for a debugging function which is not supposed to be exported, it might almost make sense to want the `_` prefix anyway...